# Assigning avatars from URL string in JSQMessagesController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I couldn't find much of use in the docs, and the sample project in Swift only had hardcoded avatars so that wasn't much help either. I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864283/user-specific-avatar-in-jsqmessagesviewcontroller-with-sdwebimage) but that example was also not applicable in my situation.

I have my user sign in with Facebook, and a graph request grabs their profile picture which is then stored in Firebase and a User object as a string (the URL path to the image I mean).

This is my `cellForItem` function

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if message.senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    return cell
}
```

And this is where I should be setting the avatars:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

    let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    if let messageID = message.senderId {
        let users = [User]()
        let userProfilePictures = users[indexPath.row].profilePicture
    }

    return ????
}
```

Anyone know how I can get the profile pictures set to the correct avatars?

EDIT: This is my image caching code:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
```

extension UIImageView {

```
func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

    self.image = nil

    // Check cache for image first
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    // Otherwise fire off a new download
    Alamofire.request(urlString)
        .responseImage { response in

            if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {
                // image is here.
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya, What you are looking for is the 'JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory' [Documentation Link](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.3.4/Classes/JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.html)

Since you have your `userProfilePicture` Then you just need to get the image data for that url. You can do this a number of ways I personally love to use a framework that handles catching for you. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) or how ever else you want to get that data.

I like `AlimofireImage` so that is what I will demonstrate here. To make it so that I do not have to keep making downloading request for each cell I save them in a dictionary using the `senderID` as a key. If the dictionary entry is there I don't make the request. Define your dictionary.

```
var avatarDictionary: [String:UIImage] = [:]
```

Then after retrieving all the messages for the conversation call `getAllAvatars()`

```
func getAllAvatars() {
    for message in messages {
        guard let key = message.senderID else { return }
        if avatarDictionary[key] == nil {
            try? _ = imageDownloader?.download(URLRequest(url: API.userPhoto(userID: key).asURL()), completion: { (response) in
                guard let image = response.result.value else { return }
                self.avatarDictionary[key] = image
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

`API.userPhoto(userID: key).asURL()` is the url to your image data source so this is what you will change for the url you have.

There are a few other methods you could also take a look into. I made my own function to give me a `defaultAvatar` for users with no image. It looks like this

```
func blankAvatar(message: Message) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource {
    return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(withUserInitials: initialsFrom(firstName: message.fistName, lastName: message.lastName), backgroundColor: UIColor.gray, textColor: UIColor.white, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
}
```

Then you can return a image if it is there or a blank avatar if not from the `avatarImageDataForItemAt` method

```
return avatarDictionary[id] == nil ? blankAvatar(message: message) : JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: avatarDictionary[id], diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))
```

Also don't forget to set the size of the avatars for the collectionView

```
 collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = avatarSize
 collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = avatarSize
```

or they wont show at all.

Let me know if you need more help .

Comment: Thanks man! I do have a function for downloading the image data with AlamofireImage, I edited my question to include it. But I can't use it - generally for a UIImage (say, if I were to be setting an image into an image view), I would just use it like `self.imageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(*url string in here*)`. But I can't do that here when I'm trying to specify the UIImage in `JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage`, the function isn't recognized and doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: I updated with my example. Would you mind selecting it as the answer. 

Comment: To be honest I'm still just as lost as before, I think my project is just set up differently from yours (https://pastebin.com/kJHQPAk8 / https://pastebin.com/9hTVVzGn) so I can't apply these suggestions. For example I don't have a `Message` class like you use in `blankAvatar`, `imageDownloader` is unrecognized, and value of type JSQMessage has no member senderID in the `getAllAvatars` function. I think I'm going to have to come back to this as I'm still relatively new, although I really did want to get the avatars up and running :( Thanks for your help though I'll accept the answer!

Comment: No man let's get this working I'll take a look at your code you have there and see what we have going. Really you can use anything for the `id` or not use it at all. I'll see what you have and make suggestions don't hesitate to ask questions on anything that you are not sure about. I know it can get confusing you just have to keep at it and really understand what things are doing and why you put it there. But ya let's keep working on this if you have time. I'll do what I can to help.

Comment: Thanks man that seriously means a lot! I'll definitely take all the help I can get, things are definitely getting really confusing with all the "moving pieces" and data getting passed between controllers etc. If you do get the time to look over my code let me know if you want to see anything else, like the `Rooms` object if that's necessary. I'm (attempting) making a group chat app so it's really exciting but seeming to be a bit more than I can handle sometimes.

Comment: Alright I looked at the code you posted and have resolved all the issues but it seems a few methods are missing or may be in other files and without the  `Rooms` object there is not much more that I can do.

Comment: You also import a few libraries that you don't do anything with. I would suggest getting things working first then look at adding support for images or other media types.

Comment: Yeah sorry I I didn't include the photo methods as I wasn't sure if they had anything to do with the avatars - this is the project with all the code (https://www.dropbox.com/s/b91bfu9w2ld10eq/SpontiStoryboard.zip?dl=0) if you want to get a broader look of what's going on, and this is the `Room` object if that's the only necessary part: https://pastebin.com/tuErA2F8. Thanks again for looking at the code - what steps should I be taking now?

Comment: Also this is what the data looks like in Firebase if that helps/matters here: http://imgur.com/a/lXebQ

Comment: We should chat do you have slack

Comment: I do, I'm @timothyjhull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139710/discussion-between-daniel-leonard-and-kingtim).